# How do I get the max speed from the Objects? And is their any way to make this code more efficient?

Tags: python

I am new to python, here i created a class to calculate speed, now i just need a way to find the max speed from the objects.

```
class CarSpeed:
    def __init__(self,name,dist,time):
        self.dist=dist
        self.time=time
        self.name=name
    
    def ans(self):
        speed= self.dist/self.time
        print(self.name,"_Speed ""(",self.dist,"/",self.time,"):",speed,"\n")
    
    
   

Ford=CarSpeed("Ford",120,1.75)
Ford.ans()

Ferrari=CarSpeed("Ferrari",100,1.20)
Ferrari.ans()

BMW=CarSpeed("BMW",205,2.35)
BMW.ans()

Porsche=CarSpeed("Porsche",155,1.85)
Porsche.ans()

Audi=CarSpeed("Audi",190,2.10)
Audi.ans()

Jaguar=CarSpeed("Jaguar",255,2.45)
Jaguar.ans()
```

I need the output in this way:
The car with the highest speed is: CAR BRAND

Comment: You may want to learn about lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: the code runs successfully, im just not able to figure out a way to get the max speed value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using max function

You can also change your `speed` to `self.speed` and add it without value to **init**

```
class CarSpeed():
    def __init__(self,name,dist,time):
        self.dist=dist
        self.time=time
        self.name=name
        self.speed = None
    
    def ans(self):
        self.speed = self.dist/self.time
        print(self.name,"_Speed ""(",self.dist,"/",self.time,"):",self.speed,"\n")
```

then you can calculate it without calling this function but from class directly by replacing `self.speed = None` by `self.speed = self.ans()`

so full code will look like this

```
class CarSpeed:
    def __init__(self, name, dist, time):
        self.dist = dist
        self.time = time
        self.name = name
        self.speed = self.ans()

    def ans(self):
        self.speed = self.dist/self.time
        return self.speed


speed_list = {}

Ford = CarSpeed("Ford", 120, 1.75)
speed_list.update({Ford.name: Ford.speed})

Ferrari = CarSpeed("Ferrari", 100, 1.20)
speed_list.update({Ferrari.name: Ferrari.speed})

BMW = CarSpeed("BMW", 205, 2.35)
speed_list.update({BMW.name: BMW.speed})

Porsche = CarSpeed("Porsche", 155, 1.85)
speed_list.update({Porsche.name: Porsche.speed})

Audi = CarSpeed("Audi", 190, 2.10)
speed_list.update({Audi.name: Audi.speed})

Jaguar = CarSpeed("Jaguar", 255, 2.45)
speed_list.update({Jaguar.name: Jaguar.speed})

fastest = max(speed_list, key=speed_list.get)
print(f"{fastest} is the fastest car")
```

Comment: + remember to write a code properly. It will help you in the future ;)
Read pep8 documentation

Comment: @GROOT See my edited post. I placed all code there.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
class CarSpeed:
    def __init__(self,name,dist,time):
        self.dist=dist
        self.time=time
        self.name=name
    
    def ans(self):
        speed= self.dist/self.time
        return speed
        
    
    
   
speed_list = {}
Ford=CarSpeed("Ford",120,1.75)
speed_list.update({Ford.name: Ford.ans()})

Ferrari=CarSpeed("Ferrari",100,1.20)
speed_list.update({Ferrari.name: Ferrari.ans()})

BMW=CarSpeed("BMW",205,2.35)
speed_list.update({BMW.name: BMW.ans()})

Porsche=CarSpeed("Porsche",155,1.85)
speed_list.update({Porsche.name: Porsche.ans()})

Audi=CarSpeed("Audi",190,2.10)
speed_list.update({Audi.name: Audi.ans()})

Jaguar=CarSpeed("Jaguar",255,2.45)
speed_list.update({Jaguar.name: Jaguar.ans()})

print(dict([max(speed_list)]))
```

Comment: heyy, thanks!.. i get an error running it tho..

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b9a059015f43> in <module>
     31 speed_list.update({Jaguar.name: Jaguar.ans()})
     32 
---> 33 print(dict([max(speed_list)]))

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class CarSpeed:
    def __init__(self,name,dist,time):
        self.dist=dist
        self.time=time
        self.name=name
    
    @property
    def ans(self):
        speed = self.dist/self.time
        return speed


cars = []
cars.append(CarSpeed("Ford",120,1.75))
cars.append(CarSpeed("Ferrari",100,1.20))
cars.append(CarSpeed("BMW",205,2.35))
cars.append(CarSpeed("Porsche",155,1.85))
cars.append(CarSpeed("Audi",190,2.10))
cars.append(CarSpeed("Jaguar",255,2.45))

fastest = max(cars, key=lambda x: x.ans)

print('The car with the highest speed is: ,'fastest.name, fastest.ans)
```

The output will be:

```
The car with the highest speed is Jaguar 104.08163265306122
```

Comment: Hii! This is perfect but I am still a beginner in python, so I dont know what the "@property" and the assigned values in "fastest" mean...    thanks for the help tho :)

Comment: Take a look at this : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property